# buttons inside scrollviewer problem

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

everyone. I couldn't find a solution to my problem eventhough I believe that others have come across this too. Basically, there are like twenty buttons in a wrap panel, which is inside a scrollviewer. The problem is that when I want to scroll the list, the click event fires the triggers. Really would appreciate help on this one.

```
<ScrollViewer>
<ScrollViewer.Content>
    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   Width="420">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource imageButtonStyle}" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cmd2:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                        CommandParameterValue="1" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>               
        </Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource imageButtonStyle}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                    <cmd2:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                     CommandParameterValue="2" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>                
        </Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource imageButtonStyle}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <cmd2:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                     CommandParameterValue="3" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>                
        </Button>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource imageButtonStyle}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                    <cmd2:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                                                     CommandParameterValue="4" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>                
        </Button>
    </toolkit:WrapPanel>
</ScrollViewer.Content>
```

Comment: is the `Click` event firing?  or the `MouseEnter` event?  i thought click happened after releasing the touch, not the touch itself.  what does MouseEnter even mean on the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a gesture listener part of the silverlight toolkit http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/52297 to differentiate between taps and flicks instead of using events

Comment: Gestures seem to be working out pretty well to resolve these types of UI ambiguity issues.